# When is it possible to replace a function in C with a macro?

Tags: c, performance, function, replace, macros

As part of an assignment I was asked to implement a list of simple functions in C and whenever possible replace those functions with a macro for runtime efficiency reasons.

Is there a general rule that helps me identify if I can replace a simple function in C with a macro? And why exactly does this replacement optimise runtime efficiency?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: As it has been pointed out by many voices here, the goal of this assignment is counter productive concerning quality of code and even efficiency in some cases.

Comment: You mean literally replace or replace semantically with some adjustments?

Comment: Macros are interpreted by the preprocessor. They have no effect whatsoever on the runtime efficiency of your code.

Comment: Too broad and opinion based. But in general, you should not use macros unless really necessary. If in doubt, use `inline` functions. Macros serve a different purpose than functions. Read: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Inline.html#Inline

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: I think the question is targeted to inlining (by macro, as OP seems not to know `inline`) vs. function call.

Comment: @cad semantically replace, im guessing. its part of an assignment with a list of functions. the task is to figure out which ones can be replaced by a macro to optimise runtime efficiency.

Comment: @Olaf i'll take a look at the other post, thanks. although i don't quite understand how the question is opinion based.

Comment: @Pietz: Instantly leave that course. The tutor apparently has no idea of C programming. I've seen quite some nonsense assignments, but that is one of the worst. It effectively teaches bad coding style. Even more, as a modern compiler very well might inline normal functions, too.

Comment: @Pietz to illustrate what Olaf (and others) mean, take for instance a look at the implementation of the getc() and other stdio macros. Or (f)lex's output... Come back if you understand what they do.

Comment: @Pietz Ask whoever gave you this assignment if he has done any real programming in this century. Replacing functions with macros is a very bad idea, especially since we have inline functions since C99 (and long before that in most compilers). Inlining can often make runtime efficiency worse and should definitely not be attempted by someone who needs to ask a question like this.

Comment: The professor is indeed very old school and all of our assignments are in C90, which explains why i haven't heard of inline functions before. anyway, thank you all for your time and recommendations. sorry for having bothered you with this.

Answer (score 3):

The only general rule is: avoid function-like macros as far as possible, because they are often unreadable and/or unsafe. You should always use a function when you can.

Function-like macros usually only make sense when dealing with compile-time issues such as constants, identifiers, declarations etc.

Replacing functions with macros for the sake of performance is not something you should even consider. It once was, some 20 years ago, because then compilers were so horrible at optimizing code that programmers did that job better than the compilers. Nowadays it is the other way, leave such things to the compiler.

Comment: its all starting to make sense now. as i said in another comment the assignment is in C90 and just so is my professor apparently. thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Pietz It doesn't really have anything to do with C90 either. There are plenty of C90 compilers that are perfectly capable of function inlining etc without the use of keywords. In fact the `inline` keyword is mostly obsolete nowadays, because it assumes that the programmer is more able than the compiler in determining what to inline.